# Looking for a Match in two excel worksheets

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

I am trying to compare a serial number field in two excel worksheets. If it finds the matching serial number I want to reflect the date in the field next to it.

```
Sheet 1
123456
654321
6789
9876

Sheet2
9876            1/1/13
123456          5/4/12
6789            6/20/13
654321          4/2/11
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `VLOOKUP` formula.

```
Sheet 1
123456          =VLOOKUP(A1;Sheet2!A:B;2)
654321          =VLOOKUP(A2;Sheet2!A:B;2)
6789            =VLOOKUP(A3;Sheet2!A:B;2)
9876            =VLOOKUP(A4;Sheet2!A:B;2)
```

`VLOOKUP(needle; matrix; index)` searches in the first column of a `matrix` for the `needle` and returns the corresponding field in column number `index`.

Comment: With that formula the value 6789 returns an error.

Comment: Well it is one and no expected output was given for those cases.

Comment: The expected output is the date next to the number in Sheet2. For the value 6789, the value next to it in Sheet2 is 6/20/2013. Your formula returns an error instead, because it looks for an approximate value in an unsorted range. Please get to know Vlookup in more detail before you advise to use it in that way.

Comment: Now I see, I misinterpreted the value as not having a corresponding key in Sheet2.

Answer (score 0):

If your data is arranged like in the sample, the Vlookup will work, but only with the fourth parameter set to False.

```
=VLOOKUP(A1,Sheet2!$A$1:$B$100,2,false)
```

Omitting the fourth parameter defaults to "true", which will require the data table to be sorted ascending by the first column. If it is not sorted and the fourth parameter is omitted, the results will be wrong for some cells.

Also, it is advisable to ringfence the lookup table to the required rows instead of using whole column references. This will impact calculation speed.

Please note that depending on your regional settings, the parameters are separated by either a comma or a semicolon. If you copy and paste a formula you may need to adjust that.